# End of Life Component Source needed

Tags: components, integrated-circuit, semiconductors

Where is the best source on the web to find authorized excess and end-of-life components?

Comment: This question is so vague that it should be closed.  We don't know what parts you are looking for, where you are, how many you need, etc.  Essentially what you asked is, "where can I buy old stuff?"  Even if we had all of that info, shopping questions are not allowed here.

Answer (score 3):

[Rochester Electronics](http://www.rocelec.com/). That's all they do. Reputable, been around for a long time.

> Under special contracts, Rochester receives all available finished
>   goods from the original component manufacturer during the EOL
>   (end-of-life) stage of the product life cycle. Rochester then becomes
>   the authorized distributor for those components - the qualified,
>   reliable solution for 100% quality product support. The original
>   manufacturers trust Rochester to continue supporting their customers'
>   requirements. Rochester does not "cherry-pick" EOL product. We
>   purchase and stock entire lots and we NEVER source from any sources
>   other than those in the authorized channel with traceability to the
>   original manufacturer.

Comment: Looking at their website, that's not all they do. At the very least, they also offer a [re-creation service](http://www.rocelec.com/semiconductor-products-services/semiconductor-recreation).

Answer (score -1):

The best supplier is the one you have a good relationship with.

Rochester Electronics are ok but one of a million "Brokers" who all deal with Chinese excess components. They ask for Certs for traceability to make them "authorized".

Unfortunately even certs and part labels can be copied.  Brokers usually belong and are self-regulated by the ERAI.  ALways ask for date codes.

Brokers know nothing about components unless they have a good Component Engineer on staff.

Prices are always inflated according to how hungry you are and availability. There are many global databases of surplus parts and it is easy to search.  Most brokers tap into the same source and there are many others.

What part # are you looking for and how many?